# Running another program in Django views

Tags: django, command, django-views

I'm working on a Django program that takes in a text file, does analyses on it, and then spits out an output text file to the user.  The way I produce the output is with another program that I've been given that uses the command "python estimator/**main**.py -v --fit path/to/score/file.txt --file_1 path/to/stats/file --out path/to/out/file" to produce an output file.  How can I call this command in a view in Python so that it can produce the output immediately after the input is uploaded?

Thanks!

Comment: Since it's a Python script, can't you just import it?

Comment: I'm a total newbie at Python.  Once it's imported, how do you use the command?

Comment: Dunno. That will entirely depend on what's in the code. Presumably it has some functions you can call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the subprocess module (included in Python) or [envoy](https://github.com/kennethreitz/envoy) (for instance) to call your process and get the output.